# How can i resize, drag and drop images in react?

Tags: reactjs

I was looking at websites like https://milanote.com/ and I am trying to implement image manipulation (functions such as dragging, resizing, cropping), and I noticed that they tend not to use HTML canvas. I've looked into react libraries that support drag and drop, but I have not found one supports image rescaling.

Any suggestions or idea to the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

[react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) is a complex grid layout system. You can set the image as a background of a grid element. There are a lot of possibilites.